# React create Bootstrap grid of unknown size

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm building an app in which I need to use React to render a Bootstrap grid. I'm a React newb so please bear with me.

Frontend will receive N objects that need to be displayed in Boostrap columns, each in his own column. The problem is, I don't know how large is N so I don't know how many rows do I need.

Any ideas how to approach this?

Should I have just one component? Or three (Container, Row, Column)? Or something else?

Comment: You can use http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/grid-list directly

Comment: But this isn't a Twitter Bootstrap grid, right? I have to use that one, it's not my call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, consider if you even need custom components for Container, Row and Column. You can just use a div with the appropriate css class, I don't see that much value in wrapping this into a custom component. If you do decide to use a custom component, you may want to look at [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#page-layout), they already implemented these.

As for the layout, I believe you can place as many columns as you want in a row in Bootstrap layout and they will wrap as necessary (if there's more than 12), so it might be easiest to just have one row and put all the columns inside it (see [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping)).

Comment: I did think about putting all the cols in just one row and let them wrap automatically, but I wasn't sure if that's the "right" way of coding it. I wrote it that way a day ago and it does act normally, wraps nicely.

Comment: Note: If you try to put all columns in a row and then the column height varies per column, then it can mess up the entire layout.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach this problem depending on the type of content that you are trying to insert into the grid.

First off, as far as columns go, Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid system. This will make your life a bit easier because you can divide 12 by the number of elements in each row. If your html is set up correctly you can use:

```
var numOfElements = document.getElementById('objectsWrapper').children.length;
```

If you're using images you may want to set a strict **max-height** and **max-width** (percentages) to restrict the images generated from messing up the grid.

Next, when the column exceeds 12 elements, you'll want to start a new **.row** if necessary. Create a new div, append it to your current container and set it as the currentDiv you want to add your children to.This step is important because your code needs to know which 'objectsWrapper' it's querying for children.

Wash. Rinse. Repeat.

Hope this helps.